# Why was this NAA flag declined?

Tags: support, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I was under the obvious misunderstanding that the `Not an Answer` flag was for flagging answers that are not answers, so imagine my surprise when I find out that's not at all what it is intended for.

[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559453/visual-basic-username-password-error/30560181#30560181) is the 'answer' in question.

Would anyone please care to explain?

Comment: That answer appears to answer the question, and is therefore an answer. If there are other reasons why you might think it should be deleted (there appear to be) then you need to explain what those are.

Comment: Your flag looks right to me; I can't see how that was an answer, especially since the OP asked further questions in the comments.

Comment: P.S., your question here is quite rude.

Comment: The relevant moderator is best-placed to answer (and may well be along shortly), but it does *look* sufficiently like an answer that this could be an honest mistake.

Comment: @Ben: The 'answer' is nothing other than a response to the accepted answer with added detail, it should be posted as a comment or edited into the question. P.S. Rude is subjective.

Comment: @TheBlueDog My sarcasm beats yours by miles!

Comment: I'm offended that you changed the title. Do you think I can't handle a little sarcasm? (wink implied)

Comment: its one of those things that you have to see and/or read the Q, the real A *and* some of the comments to see that it is a copy of the first answer. If not, a decline can seem the right thing. That guy is 3 for 3 on DV'd posts and not likely to be around long...under that name anyway.  It *is* and answer, just a bad synopsis of cybermonkey's.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I really didn't want the original title to be another whiny _OMG Y wuz ma flagz declineded_.

Comment: @Plutonix: I'm assuming he's question banned now, looks like he's back with a new account - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572990/visual-basic-password-field-error

Comment: I saw that too - I flagged it for mods as a clone/dupe account

Comment: @Plutonix: Cool, I wasn't sure how to flag it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think at first glance, it looks like it is an answer to the question. It may be inaccurate, but if someone tries to answer, then the answer could be downvoted but not deleted.

In this case, however, it seems that it's not an answer at all, but something that should have been a comment. It looks to me like your flag was right, and the person who rejected it made a mistake.

Comment: Yes, the poster of the accepted answer even commented, _Also, please do not copy my answer and add it as a new one._ I'm not usually one for whining about declined flags, but there have been some curious decisions lately.

Comment: *blames Martijn*

Answer (score 4):

It is a correct answer to the question.  A bit clumsy, clearly the OP is not a native English speaker, and not better than the accepted answer, but correct nonetheless.  Following the steps he describes solves the problem stated in the question.  It might even be useful to somebody that has similar problems mastering English.  Well, theoretically.

NAA has a high standard, it has to be gobbledegook, this post doesn't meet it by a very long shot.